EF Core: Refactor IEntityTypeConfigurations?
In EF Core we can use IEntityTypeConfiguration for a more SOLID approach for configuring our model. Is there any VS Extension or something similar existing for replacing that annoying copy&paste from the generated DbContext for those implementations by a decent refactoring?
My model has over 200 classes from Reverse Engineering...
